# How to get a sequential number of all the documents in a view

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes

How to get a sequential number of all the documents in a view. The sequential numbers will appear in a column of a view. I have used @DocNumber but it does not work when I preview my View from xpage page.

Comment: A lot will depend on which control you're using to display the view on the XPage and the programmatic name of the column in the View (last tab of the Column Properties). Seeing some code would be useful.

Comment: I am using view control in custom control to display view. and column name is $1. code of this column is below:<xp:viewColumn columnName="$1" id="viewColumn1">
<xp:viewColumnHeader value="Sr. No."
id="viewColumnHeader1">
</xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>

Answer (score 2):

See https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/List_of_Formula_Not_Supported_In_XPages. @DocNumber is not supported in XPages.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `viewPanel`, there exists one simple solution.

Set the `var` property of your `viewPanel` to some meaningful name you like, e.g.

```
<xp:viewPanel var="viewEntry" ....etc....>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

By doing this, you provide yourself an explicit access to every iteration of `DominoViewEntry` (`viewPanel` uses it internally).

Then create a view column, don't set `columnName` property, set the `value` property. Like this:

```
<xp:viewColumn value="#{javascript:viewEntry.getPosition('.')}"
    id="docNumberColumn">
        <xp:viewColumnHeader value="Doc Number"
            id="docNumberHeader">
        </xp:viewColumnHeader>
</xp:viewColumn>
```

Sorry, no way to avoid SSJS here, because `DominoViewEntry` does not expose `getPosition()` method to its `getValue()` implementation, so we have to call it directly.

Update: this should work for `dataTable` and `dataView` as well, because all of them use UIDataIterator behind the scenes and both have var property.

Answer (score 0):

Use repeat control and display the index number?